# Equality seems to work incorrectly in some cases

Tags: javascript, equality

I haven't programmed in Javascript before so maybe this is something specific to the language. I am trying to simply check whether in a list of edges that if the edge.from == currNode (this works as expected) and if edge.to == the top of priority queue consisting of nodes. The problem is that, while the LHS of the && works fine the RHS always returns false. There doesn't seem to be a problem with the frontier priority queue as when I print the top value it returns a node that, at least at the start matches one of the edge.to in frontierEdges.

This seems so strange to me because how can the exact same equality check work on a pair of node arguments but not work on another pair of node arguments? Any suggestions what might be going on?

```
if (frontierEdges[i].from == currNode && frontierEdges[i].to == frontier.peek()){}
```

Edge definition:

```
export class Edge<Node> {
    from : Node;
    to   : Node;
    cost : number;
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior when you use identity (`===`) instead of equality?

Comment: In JS, objects are equal iff  they are identical, that is, `to` and the result of `peek()` must be the same object. Obviously, `frontier`, whatever it is, returns a copy of the object that looks the same, but still not equal to the original.

Comment: If you are new to javascript, do a little reading about the differences between `!==` / `!=` and `===` vs `==` - you will almost always want `!==` or `===`

Comment: Are you maybe comparing two seperate instances of identical Nodes? Because they're objects it will check that they're the same instance.

Comment: I thought that might be part of the problem as well, but it doesn't seem to make any difference which one I use.

Comment: @georg That might be the problem. How can I make sure they are the same object or get back the original object?

Comment: @Jesper: I'll have to dig into the implementation of `peek` to find out at which point it makes a copy. A simpler option would be to use a library like lodash that provides means for "deep" (=content) comparison: https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual

Comment: @georg: I now found that there was a way to compare nodes with a function, so now it seems to work properly. Didn't really consider that peek would return a copy as opposed to the real object, but when I think about it, it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: how did you implement `frontier.peek()`?